# Laravel Twilio Store User Reply Input to Database in Response to Send SMS Order ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, twilio

I need help in Twilio getting reply responses and storing them in the database in response to sending SMS after user input in response to the message. I am sending an SMS to the user about his/her order schedule and asking him/her to confirm delivery by inputting Ok and when he/she confirm, I am getting his response successfully.

The question or the issue I am facing is that I want to know that when he/she confirm the delivery, I want to update the database record in response to the delivery SMS we sent to him/her earlier. My issue will be resolved if I am able to get order_id from the first message and send it in replytoSMS function.

My Code to send SMS and webhook (replytoSMS) are given below.

```
<?php

 public function initiateSMS(Request $request) {
  try {
  foreach ( $request->get('items') as $item ) {
    $order_id = $item['order_id'];
    $phone    = $item['phone_number'];
    $order     = Orders::where('id', $order_id)->first();

    $phone_number = $this->client->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($phone)->fetch();

  if($phone_number) {
   
      $template_value = $order->message; 

      $sms = $this->client->messages->create($phone, [
        'from' => $this->from, 
        'body' => $template_value,
        "method" => 'POST',
        "statusCallbackMethod" => 'POST',
        "statusCallback" => 'https://example.com/simply/public/api/notification/statusMessageBack?order_id='.$order_id.'',
        ]);

       // print($sms->sid);
  }
} // foreach loop end
  if($sms){
    return Response::json(['success' => 'sms initiated successfully!']);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  return Response::json(['Error' => $e->getMessage()]);
} catch (RestException $rest) {
  return Response::json(['Error' => $rest->getMessage()]);
}
}

function statusMessageBack(){
 header('Content-type: text/xml');
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
 $response = new MessagingResponse();
 $order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];
 $user_phone = $_REQUEST['To'];
 $MessageSid = (!empty($_REQUEST['MessageSid'])) ? $_REQUEST['MessageSid'] : '';
 $MessageStatus = (!empty($_REQUEST['MessageStatus'])) ? $_REQUEST['MessageStatus'] :              '';
  if($MessageStatus && $MessageStatus == "delivered"){

  $notification = Notification::create([                            
  "response_code" => $MessageSid,
  "type" => $category,
  "table_ref"  => "orders",
  "table_ref_pk"  => $order_id, 
  "response_status" => "",
  "medium" => $user_phone,
  "status" => $MessageStatus,
  "sender_id" => $sender_id
 ]);
  
}
 print $response; exit;
}

 public function replyToSMS(){
 header('Content-type: text/xml');
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
 $response = new MessagingResponse();
 $MessageSid = (!empty($_REQUEST['MessageSid'])) ? $_REQUEST['MessageSid'] : '';
 $MessageStatus = (!empty($_REQUEST['MessageStatus'])) ? $_REQUEST['MessageStatus'] : '';

$body = $_REQUEST['Body'];
$order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];
$from_phone = $_REQUEST['From'];

if (strtolower($body) == 'ok' || strtolower($body) == 'yes' || strtolower($body) == 'confirm') {
  $response->message('Your delivery has been confirmed. Thank you', [
    'callbackUrl' => "https://example.com/api/notification/reply_status?order_id='.$order_id.'",
    'callbackMethod' => "POST"
    ]);
    $notification = Notification::where('order_id', $order_id)->update(array("response_status" => "confirmed"));
 } else {
   $response->message('Sorry');
   $notification = Notification::where('order_id', $order_id)->update(array("response_status" => "call store"));
 }
  print $response;

 }

function reply_status(){
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$response = new MessagingResponse();
echo $order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];
$user_phone = $_REQUEST['To'];
$MessageSid = (!empty($_REQUEST['MessageSid'])) ? $_REQUEST['MessageSid'] : '';
$MessageStatus = (!empty($_REQUEST['MessageStatus'])) ? $_REQUEST['MessageStatus'] : '';
if($MessageStatus && $MessageStatus == "delivered"){

}
  print $response; exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SMS protocol does not any concept of additional metadata with SMS messages, nor does it have the concept of replying to a specific message (you can test this by opening your phone's SMS application and trying to respond to any message from someone that wasn't the last one you received).

You can only really tell what someone may be responding to chronologically. That is, if you have sent them a message, then their response is related to that last message that you sent.

This is an issue if you intend to send more than one message asking for a response at the same time. In this situation, we recommend you use two different `From` numbers to send the message and store that `From` number against the order in your system. That way you can tell which message was being responded to by matching up the user's phone number and the phone number that you used to send the message.

Comment: The issue is that I want to know who has confirmed the order by having order_id in response or anything that is unique for that order because each number can have multiple messages on a single day. How can I achieve this? how do I know which order has response recieved.

Comment: As per my answer, it's not possible to get a return ID in a response. The best way is to use different numbers to send the notifications and use the number they respond to to link back to the order.

Comment: Is there any other way, other than using different numbers to send notifications, the problem is we are sending multiple messages to single customers against each order and they can have multiple orders. How can I achieve that even without Twilio?

Comment: As I said originally, the SMS protocol does not have the concept of additional metadata. The only way I know of to achieve this is to use multiple numbers to send the messages. An alternative would be to force your users to include their order number in the message and you parse it out, but that is error prone and poor user experience.